# Enabling/disabling validation controls on page load with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, validation

I am using jQuery to disable validation controls in an aspx page on load. On a button press I want to enable them. I have coded the script below for this, but there is an issue. Both functions (enabling and disabling validation controls) are fired on page load.

Why are both functions being called?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad() 
    {
        $.each(Page_Validators, function(index, validator) {  
           ValidatorEnable(validator, false);
        });

        $("input[id$='btnNext']").click(enable());
    } 

    function enable() 
    {
        alert ("Enable function called");
        $.each(Page_Validators, function(index, validator){
            ValidatorEnable(validator, true);
        });
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: If you highlight all the code and click the Code Sample button (1010101), it will make this much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use document ready event in jQuery to disable the controls. Something like

```
$(function(){
    // disable controls

   $("input[id$='btnNext']").click(function(){
       enable();
   }); 
});
```

***Edit***

Replace

```
    $("input[id$='btnNext']").click(enable());
```

with

```
    $("input[id$='btnNext']").click(function(){
        enable();
    });
```